# Add user to a Group if name is partial match using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, 2016

I have a very large and complex SharePoint 2016 site with hundreds of groups.
I'm writing a powershell script to add a specific user to a group if the group's name matches some text.

For example, I need to add UserX to any group that has the word "English" in the name of the group.

I have the following code working to add to the user to an individual group, but not sure how to loop through and add them only when the partial text matches.

```
$site=get-spsite https://site
#get web object
$web=$site.RootWeb

#Enumarate site groups
$web.SiteGroups |select name
#get user object
$user=$web.EnsureUser("domain\user")
#Get group object
$group=$web.SiteGroups["Year 10 ENGLISH Staff"]
#add user to group
$group.AddUser($user)
```

Thanks for any help

Nate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following commands:

```
$site=get-spsite http://sp/sites/team
#get web object
$web=$site.RootWeb

#Enumarate names of site groups which the group name has the specific word
$web.SiteGroups | select Name | where {$_.Name -like "*English*"}

#get user object
$user=$web.EnsureUser("domain\user")
#get groups that has the specific word in the group name
$groups = $web.SiteGroups | where {$_.Name -like "*English*"}
#iterate group object
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    #add user to the group
    $group.AddUser($user)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. If I needed a more complex selection, like *English* and *staff* then would I use where {$_.Name -like "*English*" -and $_.Name -like "*Staff*"} in both places.

Comment: Have just tweaked that to include the more complex selection and it's working perfectly!